# Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) Selenium 3.6.0

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am getting an Issue mentioned in subject, which is an intermittent one. However its making our CI CD pipelines unstable so thought to get some help from geeks available on this great platform.

Since this is an intermittent issue, I don't wish to upgrade my browser version, mentioning it as this comes mostly as the suggestion.

Here are details which may help you to identify the cause which I was not able to

What libraries I use -

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '3.6.0'
gem 'capybara', '2.18.0'
gem 'site_prism', '2.11'
```

What browser I use -

```
Firefox - 52.8.0
```

Which OS I use -

```
RHEL7
```

How do I configure my driver -

```
 firefox_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  firefox_profile['browser.download.dir'] = '/tmp'
  firefox_profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
  # content-type of file that will be downloaded
  firefox_profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'application/json;application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/zip;application/x-zip;application/x-zip-compressed;application/x-rpm;application/pdf;application/xml;application/x-x509-ca-cert'
  firefox_profile['timeout'] = 480000
  firefox_profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
  firefox_profile['resynchronization_timeout'] = 90
  firefox_profile['resynchronize '] = true
  firefox_profile['dom.max_chrome_script_run_time'] = 0
  firefox_profile['dom.max_script_run_time'] = 0

  Capybara.default_selector = :css
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
  reset_wait_time
  Capybara.run_server = false
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.timeout = 240

  if ENV['LOCAL'] == 'true'
    STDOUT.puts 'starting local run'
    Capybara.default_driver = :firefox
    Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
      begin
        STDOUT.puts 'Attempting to create browser instance'
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: firefox_profile, marionette: false, http_client: client)
      rescue => e
        STDOUT.puts 'Error: Failed Attempting to create browser instance'
        STDOUT.puts e
        STDOUT.puts e.backtrace
      end
    end

    begin
      page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1200, 1200)
    rescue => e
      STDOUT.puts 'Error: Failed resize browser'
      STDOUT.puts e
      STDOUT.puts e.backtrace
    end
end
```

Error Stack Trace -

```
starting local run
Attempting to create browser instance
Error: Failed resize browser
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:89:in `connect_until_stable'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:53:in `block in launch'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:49:in `launch'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/legacy/driver.rb:47:in `initialize'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:35:in `new'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:35:in `new'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:54:in `for'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:23:in `browser'
/home/rubyuser/web-automation/cucumber/support/env.rb:63:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/invoke_in_world.rb:39:in `instance_exec'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/invoke_in_world.rb:39:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec_in'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/invoke_in_world.rb:54:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/invoke_in_world.rb:27:in `cucumber_instance_exec_in'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/hook.rb:21:in `invoke'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/before_hooks.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in before_hooks'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/action.rb:24:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/step.rb:32:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:104:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:51:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:27:in `test_step'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/step.rb:17:in `describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:27:in `each'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:22:in `block in test_case'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:17:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:104:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:51:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:34:in `around_hook'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:12:in `describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in compose_around_hooks'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:121:in `compose_around_hooks'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:26:in `block in describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:19:in `test_case'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:57:in `test_case'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/retry.rb:18:in `test_case'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:12:in `test_case'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `describe_to'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:21:in `block in done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `map'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:20:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:24:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:39:in `done'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `parse'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in `compile'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:75:in `run!'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:13:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker.rb:96:in `execute_cucumber'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker.rb:41:in `block in start'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker.rb:35:in `fork'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker.rb:35:in `start'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker_queue.rb:116:in `start'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker_queue.rb:53:in `fill'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/worker_queue.rb:35:in `process'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/runner.rb:120:in `process'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/runner.rb:100:in `run'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/gems/cukeforker-2.1.1/lib/cukeforker/runner.rb:40:in `run'
/home/rubyuser/web-automation/cucumber/Rakefile:48:in `concurrent_test'
/home/rubyuser/web-automation/cucumber/Rakefile:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@web-automation/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: GeckoDriver version?

Comment: Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: firefox_profile, marionette: false, http_client: client) => GeckoDriver is not used

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don’t want to be told to update your browser version, but the solution really is going to be putting in the time to update all of your testing gems. The version of every gem you’ve mentioned is obsolete and there have been tons of stability and timing improvements to all the mentioned gems since.

Technically, you’re actually running a version of Firefox that was never really supported by Selenium using the native Firefox driver since Selenium had moved on to focusing on WebDriver (geckodriver) by then. The real solution really is to update.

Comment: Upgrade was the only solution, and it helped to resolve the issue.